# How to use a for loop to changed consecutive values in R?

Tags: r

How can I run a loop over multiple columns changing consecutive values to true values?
For example, if I have a dataframe like this...

```
Time    Value      Bin     Subject_ID 
1         6         1         1
3         10        2         1
7         18        3         1
8         20        4         1
```

I want to show the binned values...

```
Time    Value    Bin   Subject_ID
1         6       1       1
2         4       2       1
4         8       3       1
1         2       4       1
```

Is there a way to do it in a loop?
I tried this code...

```
for (row in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df[row - 1, "Subject_ID"] == df[row, "Subject_ID"]) {
    df[row,1:2] = df[row,1:2] - df[row - 1,1:2]
  }
}
```

But the code changed it line by line and did not give the correct values for each bin.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with this for loop? If I may ask.

Comment: To change the consecutive values to just the change value for each bin. Basically go line by line looking at columns 1 and 2. Start at row 2 and subtract the amount from the previous line and use the subject ID as an index. However, doing it this way, the lines change as the loop continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still insist on using a `for` loop, you can use the following solution. It's very simple but you have to first create a copy of your data set as your desired output values are the difference of values between rows of the original data set. In order for this to happen we move `DF` outside of the `for` loop so the values remain intact, otherwise in every iteration values of `DF` data set will be replaced with the new values and the final output gives incorrect results:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                 Time    Value      Bin     Subject_ID 
1         6         1         1
3         10        2         1
7         18        3         1
8         20        4         1")


DF <- df[, c("Time", "Value")]
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df[i, c("Time", "Value")] <- DF[i, ] - DF[i-1, ]
}
df

  Time Value Bin Subject_ID
1    1     6   1          1
2    2     4   2          1
3    4     8   3          1
4    1     2   4          1
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the code in the question is that after row i is changed the changed row is used in calculating row i+1 rather than the original row i.  To fix that run the loop in reverse order.  That is use nrow(df):2 in the for statement.  Alternately try one of these which do not use any loops and also have the advantage of not overwriting the input -- something which makes the code easier to debug.

**1) Base R** Use ave to perform Diff by group where Diff uses diff to actually perform the differencing.

```
Diff <- function(x) c(x[1], diff(x))
transform(df, 
   Time = ave(Time, Subject_ID, FUN = Diff),
   Value = ave(Value, Subject_ID, FUN = Diff))
```

giving:

```
  Time Value Bin Subject_ID
1    1     6   1          1
2    2     4   2          1
3    4     8   3          1
4    1     2   4          1
```

**2) dplyr**  Using dplyr we write the above except we use lag:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Subject_ID) %>%
  mutate(Time = Time - lag(Time, default = 0),
         Value = Value - lag(Value, default = 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
   Time Value   Bin Subject_ID
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <int>
1     1     6     1          1
2     2     4     2          1
3     4     8     3          1
4     1     2     4          1
```

or using across:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Subject_ID) %>%
  mutate(across(Time:Value, ~ .x - lag(.x, default = 0))) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Time    Value      Bin     Subject_ID 
1         6         1         1
3         10        2         1
7         18        3         1
8         20        4         1"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R one-liner with `diff` in a `lapply` loop.

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1.2], function(x) c(x[1], diff(x)))
df
#  Time Value Bin Subject_ID
#1    1     1   1          1
#2    2     2   2          1
#3    4     4   3          1
#4    1     1   4          1
```

---

### Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Time    Value      Bin     Subject_ID 
1         6         1         1
3         10        2         1
7         18        3         1
8         20        4         1
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` one liner

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(c(Time, Value), ~c(first(.), diff(.))))
#>   Time Value Bin Subject_ID
#> 1    1     6   1          1
#> 2    2     4   2          1
#> 3    4     8   3          1
#> 4    1     2   4          1
```